# How make a subquery in a select all (*) for a view SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, view

I want to make a view with multiple tables, but what I need is `select * from` a table and `select` just a few from the rest of the tables. This is what I have until now:

```
CREATE VIEW `database`.`pages_view` AS
SELECT
    `p`.`p_name` AS `p_name`,
    `p`.`slug` AS `slug`,
    `i`.`image` AS `image`,
    `t`.`title` AS `title`,
    `t`.`text` AS `text`,
    `s`.`sec_name` AS `sec_name`
FROM
    (((`database`.`pages` `p`
    LEFT JOIN `database`.`page_image` `i` ON ((`p`.`id` = `i`.`pages_id`)))
    LEFT JOIN `database`.`page_text` `t` ON ((`p`.`id` = `t`.`pages_id`)))
    LEFT JOIN `database`.`sections` `s` ON ((`p`.`id` = `t`.`pages_id`)))
WHERE
    (`p`.`visible` = 1)
```

What I want is `select * from sections` instead of call one by one.

Comment: Why do you use so many round brackets?

Comment: @lad2025 is just a vice jejejeje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `s.*`:

```
CREATE VIEW database.pages_view AS
    SELECT p.p_name, p.slug, i.image, t.title, t.text,
           s.*
    FROM database.pages p LEFT JOIN 
         database.page_image i
         ON p.id = i.ages_id LEFT JOIN 
         database.page_text t
         ON p.id = t.pages_id LEFT JOIN
         database.sections s
         ON p.id = t.pages_id
    WHERE p.visible = 1;
```

Notes:

- You do not need escape characters (unless you have poorly named table or columns).
- This is especially true for table aliases.
- You don't need to rename columns to the same name `p.p_name as p_name` is redundant -- not worth the extra typing.

Also, be careful when using `*` in a view.  It is the answer to your question, but the names, types, and order of the columns depends on the underlying table.

Comment: i've already tray with * and not giving me result, thaks for the advises

Comment: That seems to be the correct answer to me.  Are you sure you have data that matches the criteria you are giving? What is the result you are expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: ops it was my mistake, a typo sorry, your answer is the correct, many thanks